# Jenkins sh script hangs when run in specific container

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, sh

I'm trying to automate deployments using the official ArgoCD docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/argoproj/argocd/dockerfile)

I've created a declarative jenkins pipeline using the kubernetes plugin for the agents and define the pod using yaml, the container definition looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml """
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: agent
spec:
  containers:
  - name: maven
    image: maven:slim
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
      - name: jenkins-maven-cache
        mountPath: /root/.m2/repository
  - name: argocd
    image: argoproj/argocd:latest
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    ...
```

I'm trying to run commands inside that container, that step in the pipeline looks like this:

```
stage('Build') {
    steps {
        container('maven') {
            sh 'echo testing' // this works just fine
        }
    }
}
stage('Deploy') {
    steps {
        container('argocd') {
            sh "echo testing" // this does not work
            // more deploy scripts here, once sh works
        }
    }
}
```

So I have two containers, one where the sh script works just fine and another where it doesn't. The sh scripts in the "argocd" container just hangs for 5 minutes and then Jenkins kills it, the exit message is: 

`process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/job-name@tmp/durable-46cefcae (running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)`

I can't do echo a simple string in this particular container.

It works fine in other containers like the official for Maven from Docker, I use to build the spring boot application. I can also run commands directly in the argocd container manually from commandline with docker exec, but jenkins just won't in the pipeline for some reason.
What could it be?

I am running the latest version (1.33) of the durable task plugin.

**Update:**
Turns out that the image for argo-cd (continuous deployment tool) *argoproj/argocd:latest* does not include other commands except `argocd`, so the issue was with the container image I tried to use and not Jenkins itself. My solution was to install the Argo-CD CLI into a custom docker container and use that instead of the official one.

Comment: Did you try to set this option `LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that by running
`System.setProperty("org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICSL", "true");
` in the Jenkins scripts console, but it didn't seem to reveal anything new.

Comment: I think that  is because the `tty: true` in your yaml

Comment: @LinPy without `tty: true` kubernetes will kill the container immediately because it's not running anything actively. I'm "abusing" the `cat` command to keep it open.

Comment: You can do it the other way just to check if it works without `tty: true`. Remove the `tty: true` option and set `command` to `sleep "3600"` and container will be active during an hour.

Comment: or better yet, use `sleep infinity`

Comment: Some way to resolve:
- Did you try to use the jnlp jenkins agent instead of maven:slim

- Did you try with label link?

- What about this yaml:
  ```kubernetes {
      label "build-test"
      defaultContainer "jnlp"
      yaml """
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: jnlp
            image: jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
          - name: okapi
            image: maven:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true  
      """
    }```

Comment: Turns out that the image for argo-cd (continuous deployment tool) does not include other commands except 'argocd', so the issue was with the container image I tried to use and not Jenkins itself.
Solution was to install the Argo-CD CLI into a custom docker container and use that instead.

Comment: It may be easier in the future to directly create ArgoCD Custom Resources that are behind the argocd cli command instead of requiring the application. This isn't all that hard and may reduce your dependencies.

Comment: @Josiah it will indeed reduce dependencies, but I actually disagree about it being easier. The CLI makes it really easy to get everything set up with just one command, that is the purpose of a CLI after all. It's more complicated to both configure and set up all resource YAML files for ArgoCD manually, in my opinion. (I did try both in the pipeline, actually).

Answer (score 8):

I've just encountered a similar issue with a custom docker image created by myself.
It turns out, I was using `USER nobody` in Dockerfile of that image and somehow, this way Jenkins agent pod was unable to run `cat` command or any other shell command from my pipeline script. Running specific container with root user worked for me.

So in your case I would add securityContext: runAsUser: 0 like below.

```
...
  - name: argocd
    image: argoproj/argocd:latest
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
...
```

Kubernetes reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-container

Comment: Thanks for this! This solved my issue!

Answer (score -2):

If the issue is Jenkins related here are some things that may help to solve the problem:

1. Issues with the [working directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1459174/jenkins-pipeline-sh-step-hangs), if you updated Jenkins from some older version the workdir was `/home/jenkins` while in the recent versions it should be `/home/jenkins/agent`
   or if you are running it in Windows the path should start with `C:\dir` and not with `/dir`
2. You can try a new clean install with `apt-get --purge remove jenkins` and then `apt-get install jenkins`
3. This is not your case as you run latest version of durable task plugin. But for other people reference versions prior to 1.28-1.30 [caused the same issue](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Durable+Task+Plugin).

If your Jenkins is clean the issue should be investigated in a different way, it seems that it's not returning an exit code to the sh command and/or the script is executed in a different shell.
I would try to do an sh file to be placed in the working directory of the container

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "testing"
echo $?
```

and try to run it with `source my_script.sh`
or with `bash my_script.sh`

$? is the exit code of the latest bash operation, having it printed will make sure that your script is terminated correctly. The [source](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) command to run the script will make it run in the same shell that is calling it so the shell variables are accessible. Bash command will run it in another subshell instead.